# Take input from text field

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I asked this question before but for some reason it says closed, but i never got the right answer,can anyone help me add a text field, where if the user types a number in text field once the number reaches the same number as the counter it displays an alert.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int NumberCount;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
int counter;
IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}
-(IBAction)minus;
-(IBAction)plus;
-(IBAction)zero;
@end
```

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)plus {
counter=counter + 1;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

-(IBAction)minus {
counter=counter - 1;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

-(IBAction)zero {
counter=0;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
counter=0;
count.text = @"0";
[super viewDidLoad];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



}

@end
```

---

I tried adding this in but it didn't work

```
if (count.text == textField ) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats"
                                                    message:@"You met that number"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}
```

My ViewController.h :

```
 __weak IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

Comment: Your previous question was closed by members of this community because it was considered too broad. Please don't repost the same question; this one will be closed too, but now as a duplicate. Instead: read your original question again and try to understand why people might think it was too broad, then click the "edit" link under the question and address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string with an UITextField object.
You have to compare the count.text string with textField.text string.

Try this:

```
if ([count.text isEqualToString:textField.text]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats"
                                                    message:@"You met that number"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}
```